# No memory with nothing on computer

Tags: windows-7

Last week I installed windows7 again because my computer stuffed up ......,
anyway when I installed it I tried to download something and it says i have no space free.

So I tried deleting heaps of stuff I don't need but still no space back.

I looked in ny computer file it has local disk which is fine, but there's another folder that's popped up called RECOVERY with 0 bytes free of 14.6. in the file it has program files, program files x86, users, recovery and windows.

How do I delete this file and get all my space back so I can download stuff and install stuff like java

Comment: How big is your hard drive? (In gigabytes)

Comment: My hard drive size of 500GB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably a virus.

I would recommend that you reinstall the operating system, as even if you remove the folder, the virus will create the folder again.

If even after reinstalling Windows does not solve the problem, do a low-level format of HDD and then install again.